# Primefaces onemenu не передает объект

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsf

Не происходит сохранения студента, при выбранном универе, причем когда можно оставить поле univer пустым, все отлично сохраняет.

Создания таблиц:

```
Table: Students
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `Students` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Surname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `univer_univerId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK8xg6lh2ugtycfqxvgopeykaoi` (`univer_univerId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK8xg6lh2ugtycfqxvgopeykaoi` FOREIGN KEY (`univer_univerId`) REFERENCES `Univers` (`univerId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


Table: Univers
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `Univers` (
  `univerId` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `avg_age` double NOT NULL,
  `label` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`univerId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Фрагмент index.xhtml

```
 <p:outputLabel value="Univer"/>
                            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{studentBean.univer}" converter="univerConverter" >
                                <f:selectItems value="#{univerBean.allUnivers}"  var="univer"
                                               itemValue="#{univer}"
                                                itemLabel="#{univer.label}"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-g-12">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="3">

                            <p:commandButton value="Create student" action="#{studentBean.addStudent}"  ajax="false"
                                             style="display: block;text-align: center"/>
```

Converter:

```
@FacesConverter(value = "univerConverter")
public class UniverConverter implements Converter {
    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, String univerId) {

        return UniverBin.getUniver(Long.valueOf(univerId));
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object univer) {
        return ((Univers)univer).getUniverId()+"";
    }
}
```

Фрагмент CDI Beans Students:

```
public void addStudent(){
    studentManagerBin.addStudent(surname, name, age, univer);

}
```

UniversBean:

```
public static  Univers getUniver(long id){
        for(Univers uni:univers){
            if(id==uni.getUniverId()){
                return uni;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Фрагмент EJB

```
public Students addStudent(String surname, String name, int age, Univers univer){
        Students student = new Students();
        student.setName(name);
        student.setSurname(surname);
        student.setAge(age);
        student.setUniver(univer);

        entityManager.persist(student);
        return student;
    }
```

Entity Students

```
 private long id;
    private String Surname;
    private String Name;
    private int age;
    @ManyToOne
    private Univers univer;
```

Entity Univers

```
    private long univerId;
    private String label;
    private double avg_age;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="univer")
    private List<Students> listOfStudents;
```

Answer (score 0):

Справился сам)))
Что нашел по теме:

1. `@Transactional` для методов, работающими с сетом сущностей `@OneToMany`;
2. Переопределение методов `equals` and `hashCode`(в моем случае);
3. Попробовать поменять аннатации области видимости CDI бинов ( у меня `@SessionScoped`
   );